# No output from cout string when the values are entered using indexes

Tags: c++

```
string l;
cin>>l[0];
cout<<l;

input:a
output:
```

According to me the code must print the value of l[0] but why is there no output?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do

```
cin>>l;
```

In your current state of code, when you try to access `l[0]` you are trying to access a memory location which may or may not be there. `cin >> l[0]` doesn't changes the size of the string which remains 0.

So when you try to do `cout << l` you are effectively printing an empty string.

Another alternative is

```
string s; 
s.resize(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an empty string. There are no characters in it, including 0th character, you trying to read into. You need to actually add characters in string:

```
std::string l;
l.push_back('\0'); //Or any other character
std::cin >> l[0];
```

Comment: instead of push_back you could do a resize. That will avoid the use of a magic character for pushing back. In some implementations it could even avoid extra allocations that may happen with push_back